# Api to connect VPN

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vpn

**How to connect to a VPN via Spring Boot API ?**
I need an JAVA API which will connect to a VPN so we can connect to that particular network where our server is located, and then we are able to hit other API's.

Comment: It's not the Spring Boot application that needs to connect to the VPN, but the underlying system needs to. If you're deploying the application to a server, that server needs to connect to the VPN

Comment: A similar question was asked a few hours ago.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113833.  The answer to this one is basically the same.  There is no Java API to connect to a VPN in general.  Some specific JPN products *may* offer Java libraries ... but a better idea is to do the connection setup outside of Java ... using whatever tools the VPN product provides.

Comment: @GregorioPalamà Thank you, but I how did server will connect to vpn ?

Comment: Thank you @StephenC for the link [is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-rest-api-which-is-behind-a-vpn-connection-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113833/is-there-a-way-to-connect-to-rest-api-which-is-behind-a-vpn-connection-in-java)